# What is the probability an event to occur in some specific time interval?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I have this problem. I want to build a predictive model of future engine breakdowns of vehicles (Buses of the public transportation). My problem consists of 2 sub-problems.

What I have as data:
1. Exact state of kilometers passed when the breakdown occurs.
2. I know how many kilometers is each bus crossing per day.
What i did so far:
1. I calculated the CPF of the  kilometers when breakdown occur since these data is coming from normal distribution.
2. ***I want to calculate the probability that some bus will reach the critical  number of kilometers(of breakdown) in the next month, assuming known daily kilometers passed.***

How can I calculate  this probability function ? I want to find the overall probability for one bus to have a breakdown in the next month, but based on the probability function of the kilometers when breakdown occurs and the probability a bus to reach those kilometers in some specific time.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are looking for [Survival Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). A typical non-parametic model is the Kaplan-Meier estimator. If assumptions are met you can also consider a Cox Proportional Hazards model.

Comment: Hello @klumbard. Thank you very much for your fast response. I've already taken a look to the Survival Analysis and I am pretty much sure that i can find my solution by using it. However, I am pretty much new with these topics and I have still some uncertainties in terms of how to set my data in order to fit it to the survival analysis. Apparently, I have over 1000 different buses which occur in breakdown 1-2 times during their lifetime and i have the data for the last 10 years. 
Maybe I should take just a sample and test how many buses of this sample will reach the critical KM in 1 week?

Comment: Survival Analysis deals with "time to event" data. In your case, the "event" is "bus breaks down". Now typically, the event only occurs once and then never again...modeling buses that break down multiple times is a bit more complex. The nice thing about survival analysis is that you can also use information from the buses that DON'T break down. This is called "censoring". You should begin by researching "Survival Function" and seeing how it relates to your problem. Past that, I would recommend re-posting this in stats.stackexchange.com if you want more specific advice.